# How to get the RealProxy when I know only the transparent proxy

Tags: .net, wcf, realproxy, transparentproxy

I have a transparent proxy, for instance one generated by WCF:

```
        ChannelFactory<ICalculator> channelFactory = 
            new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(
              new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
              "net.pipe://localhost/WcfTransparentProxy/Calculator" );
        ICalculator calculator = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
```

How do I get the RealProxy from the transparent proxy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a function in RemotingServices specifically for this:

`System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.GetRealProxy( transparentProxy );`

Comment: do you know how i can detect the proxy type by just providing th ip, port. is there any class for this in .net