# Add OperationContracts to a ServiceContract dynamically

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a WCF application and I need to create "routes" so OperationContracts dynamically based on some dlls.

Here's what it looks like

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ImyWebService
{
    [OperationContract] //Login to web server
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = @"/login")]
    LoginResponse MyLogin(LoginRequest request);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, MaxItemsInObjectGraph = int.MaxValue)]
public class WebService : ImyWebService
{
    public LoginResponse MyLogin(LoginRequest request)
    {

    }
}
```

We can see that MyLogin is statistically defined, but I'd like to add other OperationContract during the runtime.

Is that possible? All the solutions I've found yet don't fit well with my use.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing that? (by answering this you might shed some light on what proper solution is) How WCF clients would be able connect to such "dynamic" service contract?

Comment: By querying which plugins are present on the server, we should see that more like a RESTful api

Comment: Shouldn't you abstract plugin by custom type not a method (OperationContract)? So you have common methods like `IResult DoOperation(IPluginSpecific)`

Comment: Each plugin has a ServiceContract interface and it's implementation, the perfect thing would be to add all the OperationContract contained in a specific dll into my WebService.

Comment: Then you need kind of self made routing to route call depends on type to aprticular service contract probably with intermediate request type adoption

Comment: I've not found a good solution yet, I mean to achieve what you've said

Comment: Are all possible OperationContracts known in advance?

Comment: No, they are not during the compilation, some OperationContracts would come from dlls.

Comment: Like you put in a folder some DLL and WCF automatically exposes its methods?

Comment: Ok let's imagine you have such dynamic API service, how would its clients would be able create proxy if contract might change or do you want client proxies so automatically regenerated every time? I'm missing some point because we can solve mostly any technical problem but it might be wrong direction if not taking into account main aims of entire solution/problem so would be great if you describe entire final architecture

Comment: And just generation on server side - a C# example http://stackoverflow.com/a/9619685/485076, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328552/Calling-a-WCF-service-from-a-client-without-having

Comment: Thank you @sll for the help, I've found my solution, I've answered to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = @"*")]
    GenericResponse Post(GenericRequest request);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = @"*")]
    GenericResponse Get();
```

This, my friends, is the key! `UriTemplate = @"*"`
The star "*" `UriTemplate` redirect all the requests to the specified method.
Behind that I only had to create a routing system.